# How to append multiple dataframe using a for a loop in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple `"cycle_end_date"` column. I want to make a new dataframe with each `cycle_end_date` and get SMS and FLASH Metrics to them.

Inputs:
The SMS table is different and FLASH table is also different

SMS Table:

```
cycle_end_date  Sms_delivered 
30th Sept        100
15th Oct         150
```

In the same way even flash table is there.
I made new dataframes of unique cycle_end_date values using : `dfs = dict(tuple(flash_table.groupby('t_cycle_end_date')))`
and then `transform` on them to get my desired dataframe.
Basically this:

```
cycle_1 = dfs['2021-09-30']
cycle_2 = dfs['2021-10-15']
cycle_3 = dfs['2021-10-31']
```

and then:

```
cycle_1 = cycle_1.transpose()
cycle_2 = cycle_2.transpose()
cycle_3 = cycle_3.transpose()
```

However for every date I am getting the desired dataframe but I am unable to append them in format I require:

Desired output

```
Cycle_end_date  30th Sept
                 SMS       Flash
Delivered        100       2000
Sent             150       3000
Cycle_end_date  15th Oct
Delivered        150        200
Sent             250        250
```

How do I do that? I have 12 cycles. Can I make a for LOOP? I am confused. I am printing each dataframe and then copy pasting numbers to excel for my report. Is there a better way?

UPDATE!!!!!

```
all_dfs = [cycle_1, cycle_2, cycle_3]


for df in all_dfs:
    df.columns = ['Metrics']
    df.index.name = 'cycle_end_date','b'

pd.concat(all_dfs)
```

I tried this and it gives me a similar format. How do I change the index name? for now this

```
                                                   Metrics
(cycle_end_date, b) 
a                                                 2021-09-30
b                                                 1.03854e+06
```

I want to rename a and b with delivered and sent

Comment: all_dfs = [cycle_1, cycle_2, cycle_3]

for df in all_dfs:
    df.columns = ['Metrics']
    df.index.name = 'cycle_end_date','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'

pd.concat(all_dfs)

I tried this. It gives me the above output but how do I change the index names?

Comment: You included a desired output but didn't include an input that you want to be transformed into the desired output

Comment: Hi, the first dataframe (SMS Table ) is my input. The same way there is a flash_table. Can u please check?